# mplayer command line video cropping

Tags: video-editing, mplayer

I am trying to crop a video using `mplayer` command.
`mplayer -vf crop=672:570:8:6 golf.mp4`
This command gives me the preview of the video(golf.mp4) with cropped ratio but i am not sure how to save/ store it. Can any one help me to store the cropped video as a separate video file?

Comment: I believe mencoder is the counterpart to mplayer for saving to file. Not familiar with its syntax, though.

Comment: @Mulvya Other than FFmpeg, do you have any other command line cropping solution?  thanks